# MuleSoft deployment failing using maven

Tags: maven, mule, anypoint-studio

I am trying to deploy a flow I created in Anypoint Studio to CloudHub using maven. I have my pom.xml configured as best as I can tell:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>capgemini</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>mule</packaging>
    <name>Mule maven-test Application</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <mule.version>3.9.0</mule.version>
        <mule.tools.version>1.2</mule.tools.version>
        <cloudhub.domain>mydomain</cloudhub.domain>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/app/</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/api/</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>mappings/</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <deploymentType>cloudhub</deploymentType>
                    <muleVersion>3.9.0</muleVersion>
                    <username>myusername</username>
                    <password>mypassword</password>
                    <applicationName>circleci-maven</applicationName>
                    <redeploy>true</redeploy>
                    <target>Cloudhub</target>
                    <domain>${cloudhub.domain}</domain>
                    <targetType>server</targetType>
                    <environment>Development</environment>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Mule Dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfrog.maven.annomojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-anno</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-core-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Transports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jdbc-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jms-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mule Modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
          <repository>
            <id>Central</id>
            <name>Central</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-release</id>
            <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

And I keep getting the following error:

```
[INFO] No application configured. Using project artifact: C:\workspace\maven-test\target\maven-test-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.zip
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.383 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-03T10:33:29-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:2.2.1:deploy (default-cli) on project maven-test: Execution default-cli of goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:2.2.1:deploy failed.: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

I have tried changing things around but can't seem to find anything that works or a detailed explanation of how to get the thing to work. Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here. `target`, `targetType` and `domain` are not applicable for CloudHub deployments via the mule-maven-plugin, and you need to provide some more info (like `workerType`) Make sure you specify `businessGroup` as well. Here's an example of a configuration that has yielded a successful deployment for me in the past:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <skip>false</skip>
    <deploymentType>${deployment.type}</deploymentType>
    <muleVersion>${mule.version}</muleVersion>
    <username>${username}</username>
    <password>${password}</password>
    <applicationName>${application.name}</applicationName>
    <environment>${arm.environment}</environment>
    <businessGroup>${business.group}</businessGroup>
    <region>${region}</region>
    <workerType>${worker.type}</workerType>
    <workers>${workers}</workers>
    <redeploy>${redeploy}</redeploy>
    <properties>
      <env>${mule.env}</env>
      <vault.key>${vault.key}</vault.key>
    </properties>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>deploy</id>
      <phase>deploy</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>deploy</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

You can replace the placeholders with your values. Information on what all these fields are can be found [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/mule-maven-plugin#cloudhub) in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much. And what are the options for mule.env and vault.key. I'm not sure what I'm supposed to put there

Comment: Those were project-specific properties that I was passing up to CloudHub. You won't need those yourself; they're completely optional.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks again